# i am having trouble loading an svg

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.white,
elevation: 0,
leading: IconButton(icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/back.svg"), onPressed: (){}),
),
);
}
}

Comment: my flutter svg is flutter_svg: ^0.17.4

Comment: The latest version is 2.0.5. Always upgrade to get the best result. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg. NOTE:There are certain limitations with this package. It won't load and show expected result if there's a shadow or gradient.

Comment: Use the latest version of the package and make sure you are using the correct path.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a conflict between the flutter_svg and material libraries, it's likely due to a namespace collision. This can happen if there are classes with the same name in both libraries.

For example, there is a Picture class in both the flutter_svg and material libraries. In this case, you can use an alias when importing the flutter_svg library to avoid the collision.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart' as svg;

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget { 
 const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
 return Scaffold( 
   appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
    elevation: 0, 
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: svg.SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/back.svg"), 
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    ), 
  ), 
  ); 
 } 
}
```

In this example, the flutter_svg library is imported with the alias svg, so you can use svg.SvgPicture.asset instead of SvgPicture.asset.